# Firebase doesn't update token after call getToken(true)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, i am using the combination of:

```
//retrieve actual token
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener

//force delete instance and then get a new token
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

But both are deprecated, and now i'm trying to use the combination of

```
//retrieve actual token
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener 

//force get new token
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true).addOnSuccessListener
```

To achieve the same behavior, but its not working.

When i call  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance() it gives me a different token of  FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken

For example:

On app start, FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token give me the token:

```
abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc...
```

Then, when i call FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true), i receive the token

```
123123123123123123123123123...
```

I close the app, open again, and FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token gives me the same old token:

```
abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseInstanceId is not the same as messaging token. You should use `Firebase.messaging.token` to get the current token and `Firebase.messaging.deleteToken()` to force get a new one.

Or without ktx extensions: `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()` and `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken()`

Comment: I have tried Firebase.messaging.deleteToken() and in then Firebase.messaging.token, but it returns the same token, doesnt update

Comment: maybe you are trying to get a new token before the current one was deleted. Try this `deleteToken().addOnSuccessListener { getToken() }`

Comment: I thought the token generated on deleteToken() was the same, because (coincidence) always started with the same characteres on beginning, but it was different from half to end. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks @SinneroftheSystem this one is perfect solution :-   FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken().addOnSuccessListener {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
        }